# C++ Set Wallpaper

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Всем привет, надо мне сменить фон рабочего стола, юзаю функцию `SystemParametersInfo()`
`"Windows.h"` подключил, путь прописал, по нажатию кнопки должна поставиться картинка, но ставиться черный фон.
Менял картинку и на bmp, и слешы другие ставил, все равно тот же результат.
Ставил левый путь к файлу,и тоже черный фон :(

Код:

`SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 1,
 (PVOID)"C:\\Users\\HP\\Pictures\\wallpaper.png", SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Параметр `uiParam` должен быть нулём:

```
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0,
  (PVOID)"C:\\Users\\HP\\Pictures\\wallpaper.png", SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
```

Также проверьте, что вы компилируете приложение без поддержки юникода. Если с поддержкой, то надо так:

```
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0,
  (PVOID)L"C:\\Users\\HP\\Pictures\\wallpaper.png", SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, помогло)